# jQuery: Reload a DIV which was already loaded by AJAX (without url)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I load a div by a simple

```
 $('#thediv').load("theurl/param1/param2/param3");
```

The params differ - and I grab them from different points - depends on where the user clicks. (Different filter options..)

Now I'm searching for a simple way to reload this content with the url it was actually loaded - to avoid searching for the right filter params at this place. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will not "save" the source of information on its own, but it is possible to specify it manually using the .data() method alongside the initial .ajax()

This means during the initial load, you can associate a URL with a div by saying something like .data("source-url","MY URL GOES HERE")

After that, you can look up that information the next time you want to reload it by using .data("source-url")

**For Example:**

```
function reloadDivs() {

  // Look up all of the divs that we might want to reload
  $("div.reloadable").each(function(i,el) {

    // For each div, check to see if the source-url was set
    // If it was set, re-run the ajax call
    var $el = $(el);
    if($el.data("source-url")
      $el.load($el.data("source-url"));
  });
}

$(function() {
    // Set the initial source, change mypage.html to your actual source
    $("#example-div").data("source-url","mypage.html");
    $("#refreshbutton").click(reloadDivs);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx. It does the trick - but only if I add a blank data-source-url="" to the div. He doesn't seem to add data fields... only change them. Is that correct?

Comment: Definitely take a moment to look at the .data() method and documentation.  You can dynamically specify (or initially set) the data using it, but you need to decide when the right time for doing that would be.  My example was not perfectly matching what you want to do, but was more of a "tech demo"